# Add up all values in column P that has the same value in column A that come from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables joined and I was wanting to add up the value in the price column with ones that had the same value in the EmployeeID column

```
EmployeeID  Price
2            8
2            5
2            11
2            8
3            6
3            8
5            13
5            16
6            13
8            5
9            10
9            4

Select o.EmployeeID,p.Price
From Orders o
inner join Product p on o.ProductID=p.ProductID
```

(This is the code I used to display the 2 columns from separate tables.)

```
EmployeeID  Price
2            32
3            14
5            29
6            13
8            5
9            14
```

This is what I want the table to look like

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `group by` statement for aggregating values referring to the same attribute. I.e., in your case, the solution might look like

```
select o.EmployeeID, sum(p.Price)
from Orders o
inner join Product p on o.ProductID=p.ProductID
group by o.EmployeeID
```